# how to print map in c++ without using iterator

Tags: c++, stl

Is it possible to print map in c++ without using iterator ?
something like

```
map <int, int>m;
m[0]=1;
m[1]=2;

for(int i =0; i<m.size(); i++)
    std::cout << m[i];
```

Is it necessary to make iterator for printing map value ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use iterators?

Comment: @Satus I am just curious to know what are the other ways to print map values other than iterator

Comment: well, that wouldn't make much sense, since `map` is designed to be used as dictionary (key-value) storage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you simply want to avoid typing out the iterator boilerplate, you can use a **range-for loop** to print each item:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<int,std::string> m = {{1, "one"}, {2, "two"}, {3, "three"}};

    for (const auto& x : m) {
        std::cout << x.first << ": " << x.second << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5f7eac88d67dafe

Ranged-for: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Obviously, this uses the map's iterators under the hood...

Comment: Of course, this is merely syntactic sugar for "using iterator" ;)

Comment: but.. this is an iterator :(

Answer (score 1):

> Is it necessary to make iterator for printing map value ?

Yes you need them, you can't know what keys been inserted in advance. And your code is not correct, think about

```
map <int, int>m;
m[2]=1;
m[3]=2;

for(int i =0; i<m.size(); i++)
    std::cout << m[i];  // oops, there's not m[0] and m[1] at all.
                        // btw, std::map::operator[] will insert them in this case.
```

Comment: @vidhugangwar Did you try my code? Is it expected behavior for you? http://ideone.com/iYeccm